# Trouble implementing splash animation into Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-splash-screen

I want to have an animation as my splash screen in my React Native expo app.
I'm using the `expo-splash-screen` library to try to implement this, but all I'm getting when I launch my app is a blank white screen instead of the animation. Any ideas why?

Here's how I've set up my app.

**App.js**

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MyStack } from './routes/homeStack';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'

export default function App() {

  const [ fontsLoaded ] = useFonts({
    'Sofia-Pro': require('./assets/Sofia_Pro_Regular.otf'),
    'Helvetica-Neue': require('./assets/HelveticaNeue-Medium.otf'),
    'NunitoSans': require('./assets/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf'),
    'LatoRegular': require('./assets/Lato-Regular.ttf')
  })

  

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <MyStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**app.config.js**

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default {
  expo: {
    name: "Gig Fort",
    slug: "gig-fort",
    version: "3.0.0",
    orientation: "portrait",
    icon: "./assets/icon.png",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/gigFort_splash_animation.json",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      // backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0,
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],

    android: {
      googleServicesFile: "./google-services.json",
      icon: "./assets/icon.png",
      package: "******",
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: "******"
        }
      },
      versionCode: 3
    },
    web: {
      favicon: "./assets/favicon.png",
    },
    extra: {
      firebaseApiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      eas: {
        projectId: "******",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I've read that GIF files are not supported in React Native, so I converted my animation to JSON, which I've verified as being valid JSON. I've also checked that the 'image' property in 'app.config'json' is pointing to the right file.

Comment: Got any solutions??